# Should the minimum title length check apply for retagging?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, title

When retagging [Should I upgrade to Ruby 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587271/should-i-upgrade-to-ruby-1-9), I had to edit the title too, because the original was too short.

Is this kind of check intended for mere retags? What happens if someone has the rep to retag a question, but not edit the title without suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, that question is too localized and should not exist at all -- so the reminder that "hey, this question predates our title length rules" is a reminder that we should *re-evaluate the whole question* not just the title rule..

Comment: I wish it were too localized. :(

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: And yet it is still open.  No, wait, I just closed it.

Comment: @won I think Andrew was saying it's still relevant since Ruby 1.9 even after a year is still sketchy. I know nothing of this topic..