# Able to break the minimum title length restriction?

Tags: bug, title, character-limit

I was trying to format code in [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14090563/1), but it wouldn't submit because "The title is too short, minimum 15 characters." I had not changed the title, so the original version must have suffered from the same problem.

How was the OP able to create a question with a 13-character title? I tried to do that and I failed. I tried [consecutive spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10884/147640), that didn't work either.

(Seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109072/147640). Nobody seems to be surprised that a short-title question made it to the system in the first place. Why? Apparently not because a [recent change in rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10883/147640), there were none.)

Comment: Special characters get stripped from a title. I assume OP padded the length with a couple of those (maybe more, who knows), they were automatically removed server side, bringing the count down to 13.

Comment: @Asad Likewise, spaces are also removed, and the title length is checked after the trim; should really be same for special characters.

Comment: That must have been changed then, because it used to be possible to use a bunch of whitespace to workaround this. I just noticed you've already tried this approach.

Answer (score -13):

The author may have wrapped the question in other characters, such as -==- (as can be seen in the revision history of [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/11398/revisions)) and then a moderator may have removed them. At least, this happened to me once before but I do not remember the site.

It cannot be white-space because white space is stripped out before the length-check is applied.

Comment: And you really couldn't come up with a better title in that case? Why wrap a lousy title in nonsense characters, when you could simply take the time to make it a good one?

Comment: You defention of good and bad is based on the stackoverflow automatic title. I like to see how peoples brain is formatted by machines. I also like to see how they demonstrate the double standards: You massively upvote the question which asks for filter bypass to create a bad title and downvote the question that answers how to do that. This is machine-formatted brain with double standards.

Comment: Nah, my **definition** of a good title is based on plenty of experience writing them, or adjusting the bad titles of the posts of others. "Genotypic IQ" is a poor title that tells me very little about the exact question you're going to ask. Additionally, wrapping this in nonsense is not only lazy on your behalf, but deferring the editing of it to others is just poor form. Stop doing that please.

Comment: Your definition of good and bad is based on the context. If nobody asks any more questions about genotypic IQ (the most probable assumption) in the whole lifetime of stackexchange, there is no reason to add more details into the title. I have asked the most general question and given the most general title. The title does not need any more details. Your assessment of this particular title is wrong.

Comment: Terrible title, I donnow what you're talking about but could write a couple of better titles to that -=IQ=- question.

Comment: Might be for you, to comply your quality title standards I had to have something like *"Genotypic IQ that was discussed in email with Helmuth Nyborg, a notable psychologist and conflicting tendencies exposed when contrasted with phenotypict IQ with references to the book of Arthur Jensen"*. I won't do that. Go your hell yourself. BTW, why not -=genotypic=-? Doble standards again?

Comment: If that is the only alternative you could think of, perhaps you really need [some good tips on writing decent titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).

Comment: Very good recommendations. My title complies to them completely. Particularly, it is of the form *"PostgreSQL encrypted backups"*. If you have MySQL and want simple (not encripted) backups, you write *"MySQL backups"*. You do not write *"MySQL not compressed not necessary engripted backups"* to make the filter happy. So, have to claim that my title is bad because it complies with your FAQ standards.

Comment: Seems to me even "How can IQ be genotypical?" better summarizes that question. And yes, "MySQL backups" is a terrible title too.

Comment: Indeed, "MySQL backups" does not comply the 15-char filter. "PostgreSQL encrypted backups" is much better. "How can IQ be genotypical?" is not better at all. It asks the same thing. Any person exposed to "genotypical IQ" will ask "what the hell is that?" What is the genotypical IQ? How can IQ ever be genotypical? These are all the same questions/titles. I chosen the shortest one, as your FAQ recommends.

Comment: *"How can IQ be genotypical?" [...] asks the same thing.* No, it does not. Simply try to answer "Genotypic IQ". There's no hint whatsoever about *what* is being asked there.

Comment: "Genotypic IQ" begs the answer: what the hell is that? Also, there is a text of my question if you do not understand that. Title must just tell you what the question is about. It must not be the question itself. Your comment implies otherwise. I will write my titles as questions only when you leave only the title and remove the question textfield.

Comment: We're creating questions, not surprise gifts.

Comment: `The question was: how to bypass the length filter? I have answered it: you can do that with the help of moderator.`  -- no, the question wasn't how to bypass the filter. The question was a) how the hell that user bypassed the filter, and b) how to make sure people don't bypass filters in future. There was no moderator intervention in that question, so it wasn't moderator who shortened the title for the user. That alone makes your answer wrong, which is partially the reason it has so many downvotes now. It is definitely *not* an example of "right answers are closed."

Comment: *Title must just tell you what the question is about.* No. While you were typing your question the title's placeholder clearly stated: *What's your biology question? Be specific.* Why not simply take a few seconds to do that? Also, the title is needed to show you the possible existing duplicates.

Comment: @Arjan, my question is unique (and will always be). That is why you attribute the duplicates issues to it. Tell about the duplicate issues to those who propose the model questions like  "PostgreSQL encrypted backups".

Comment: There could never be annother question about genotype IQ?!

Comment: There could never be another question about "PostgreSQL encrypted backups"? I appreciate your double standards.

Comment: @GSerg If you do not accpet the new ways to bypass the filter then why do you accpet them? Why is this question still open? So, you keep placing everything upsidedown. Legitimate questions are closed, closed are kept open in order you could declare correct answer as not answer. And, after that, you say that you do not put things upside down? I think this extra fact contributes to your collection of perverted things. Thank you for teaching me order and clarity.

Comment: This question is about how it happened and how we can prevent it in the future. Not how we can continue this behaviour

Comment: @RichardTingle do you answer the question to GSerg because you have nothing to object in my question to you? Is is what you want to say? But thank you for the opportunity to unfold my question: why does this question does not clarify that no bypasses other than that revision are accepted? Why does GSerg still talks about filter bypassing methods in general? How can you prevent bypassing if you do not listen about as much methods of bypass as possible? What is the point of keeping the question open, once you have closed that hole and do not listen about others?

Comment: Finally, the link to the revision in question is broken today. How am I supposed to know that the problem was not moderator edit? How did others know that? Thank you for teaching me order and clarity.

Comment: Look at [java "incompatible types"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+“incompatible+types”). There is an infinitude questions like "Incompatable types", "Q:Trouble with incompatible types", "Q:Java:Incompatible Types". Now, you downvote the asked filter bypass method because nobody but me ever asked and will never ask about the "genotype IQ". Sorry, but I cannot presume any common sense from you. All you need to understand is that depending on the popularity and pecularity of the issue, two words may be good where > 10 is insufficient for others. You cannot apply single len-filter to all.

Comment: Nothing is catch all, a very short title is less likely to explain the issue and is more likely to clash with non duplicates.

Comment: If you disagree with the filter you should propose changing it, you are receiving down votes because (a) you are suggesting "cheating" the filter rather than suggesting it be removed and (b) you are suggesting making huge quantities of unnessisary work for moderators

Comment: @RichardTingle Actually, the fact that I show how you can cheat while you consider it bad does not mean that there is not breach in the filter. Thank you for changing arguments all the time. This keeps teaching cliarity and order to me. Thank you for not mentioning the problem of the length that I have exposed to you. The minimal length must be increased to 60 characters at least for all titiles since typical java error messages are all duplicates. Thank you for formality instead of common sense.

Comment: Unless I have considerably misunderstood; you have proposed it as a good thing to do this, rather than "I am reporting this exploit I have discovered which should be closed". If you would like to discuss the minimum title length I am happy to do so, however that should have it's own question

Comment: P.s. I think you should reread the question as I think you have considerably misunderstood it's context. It is asked in the context of the police investigating a crime rather than criminals attempting to plot their next crime. You have answered as if it was the second type of question

Comment: @RichardTingle At first, you is a first one who came up with theшы "reason" on 105th comments, once evertything was downvoted already under different pretexts. Secondly, there is no requirement that the person who gives the answer has the same motivation as one who asked for it. The only thing what is important is if OP is looking for bypasses or not.

Comment: And he has already clearly stated *"no, the question wasn't how to bypass the filter"*.

Comment: Finally, I forgot that I have already provided an example of `much better` title http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160875/able-to-break-the-minimum-title-length-restriction/204778#comment655083_204778 because "much longer title is more likely to explain the issue and is less likely to clash with non duplicates". Despite of this absolute truth, it was rejected by your community.

Comment: @Bart, You had to mention that Richard Tingle had to come up with another reason, after I exposed how terribly unreasonable your complaint is.

Comment: Ok, the useful part of your answer is "The OP may have wrapped their title in noise characters such as -==- and then a moderator may have deleted them" Everything else is noise and your political opinion which is not on topic for this question

Comment: @RichardTingle Nevertheless, you invented all kinds of unjustified attack on it, generating what?

Comment: @Val you did ask why this was getting downvotes but the origional question wasn't

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, and nobody did explain that they want to see this -==- constructive part. Instead, they started to attack me with unjustified claims, confirming my "political philosophy".

Comment: I have edited to leave only the parts that answer the question, hope you're happy with it. I think this answer would not have recieved down votes

Comment: The rest (regarding whether the length check is a good thing) could find a place in annother question, but not here

Comment: Can a moderator actually submit (save) short titles? (That would introduce problems for regular users trying to edit [or retag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106341/should-the-minimum-title-length-check-apply-for-retagging) at a later time.)

Comment: No, @Arjan. IIRC, there's a scenario that involves characters being stripped that can result in *anyone* posting a shorter title, but moderators have no special dispensation with regard to such limits.

Comment: Re your other question, [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160875/able-to-break-the-minimum-title-length-restriction/204778#comment655190_204778) is the someone saying previously that moderators cannot edot in short titles

Comment: Your link is broken. Here, Shog9 says that *Anyone can edit*.